# Print redirect results inside array

Tags: php, redirect

Im unable to print the results inside my $rez ,

I tried to do it like this

```
$rez = get_all_redirects('https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Av0ED-8X5JXO-ZDMDo-f3fb0173?tl=1');
print_r($rez);
```

But it only print Array()

My full code is below

What im trying to accomplish is to to trace all redirects to one link and print them.
Unfortunately im unable to succeed.
Whatever I try , it print either array () or the first redirection link

```
<?php
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 
 
    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';
      
    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;
      
    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);
 
    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
        if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
            return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
        else
            return trim($matches[1]);
  
    } else {
        return false;
    }
     
}
 
/**
 * get_all_redirects()
 * Follows and collects all redirects, in order, for the given URL. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_all_redirects($url){
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
        if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
            break;
        }
        $redirects[] = $newurl;
        $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}
 
/**
 * get_final_url()
 * Gets the address that the URL ultimately leads to. 
 * Returns $url itself if it isn't a redirect.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_final_url($url){
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects)>0){
        return array_pop($redirects);
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}

;

$rez = get_all_redirects('https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Av0ED-8X5JXO-ZDMDo-f3fb0173?tl=1');

function printVar($rez) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($rez); 
    echo '</pre>';
}


?>
```

Comment: Looking at the [code from 2008](https://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/07/05/how-to-get-redirect-url-in-php/) which this is based on, `get_all_redirects` only gets redirects. If no redirects happen an empty array is returned. Also, all of the `return false` items might be better served with exceptions so you can see the failures.

Comment: the link https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Av0ED-8X5JXO-ZDMDo-f3fb0173?tl=1 has multiple redirects , so why it shows my and empty array with that 

$rez = get_all_redirects('https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Av0ED-8X5JXO-ZDMDo-f3fb0173?tl=1');
print_r($rez);

Comment: Not sure. See my note about checking for errors.